# Thesaurus Option is empty?

Tags: autocompletion

I recently started looking at completions, and it says in the help if I am in insert mode and press CTRL+X CTRL+T I should be able to bring up a thesaurus of other words in a drop-down completion, but it just says `thesaurus option is empty`.

How do I set my `thesaurus option`, and can I do the same thing for the dictionary?

Comment: It says there's an example file at: `ftp://ftp.ox.ac.uk/pub/wordlists/` but I don't see any host there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it just says `thesaurus option` is empty.

To use the thesaurus in vim, option thesaurus has to be defined in .vimrc, pointing to the location of the thesaurus text file.

Use

`set thesaurus+=<file>.txt`   * *Replace `<file>` with the file location*

---

You can define your own thesaurus using

Steps :

1. `touch thesaurus.txt`
2. write `important,valuable,substantial,significant` inside it and `:wq`
3. link to the file in .vimrc using `set thesaurus+=/home/thesaurus.txt`
4. **enjoy** your newly created thesaurus using `Ctrl+x Ctrl+t`

But...but...

Making thesaurus for every word is so laborious which is why you can download a thesaurus like [Moby thesaurus](http://moby-thesaurus.org/) which has about 20 synonyms for every word!

[Alternate link to moby](https://github.com/zeke/moby/blob/master/words.txt) word.txt

link it to .vimrc and **enjoy**

Comment: this file isn't exactly in the format vim wants; vim thinks every word in a phrase is a different entry